# Como pasar una variable de javascript a un php externo

Tags: php, javascript, funciones, variables

Tengo una función de javascript en la cual obtengo una variable que necesito utilizar en otro fichero php diferente y no se como hacerlo. Les muestro el codigo de los ficheros, gracias de antemano.

**Fichero JavaScript (prueba1.html)**

```
function boton() {

  var id_nombre=document.formConductor.selector.value;
  $.post("prueba2.php", [id_nombre]);
  alert (id_nombre);
}
```

**Fichero PHP (prueba2.php)**

```
$conductor = $_POST["id_nombre"];
print $conductor;
```

Comment: Estás usando jQuery para el `$.post`?

Comment: Verifica en el inspector de elementos del navegador que los mas probable es que no reconozca la url

Comment: Intenta imprimiendo lo que te trae el `POST`

Comment: prueba `$.post("prueba2.php", 'id_nombre='+id_nombre)`;

Comment: para mejorar el código podrías obtener el valor del select por su id. Así: `id_nombre =$("#idselect option:selected").val();`

Answer (score 3):

Deberías pasarle como un objeto al [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) los valores.

```
function boton() {
  var id_nombre = document.formConductor.selector.value;
  $.post('prueba2.php', { id_nombre: id_nombre }, function(data) {
    // Hago algo con esa data
    console.log(data);
    // Esto te imprime en la consola el dato que le enviaste como id_nombre
  });
}
```

Y en tu PHP:

```
$conductor = $_POST["id_nombre"];
// siempre es conveniente hacerle un encode a json
echo json_encode($conductor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `ajax` para lograr esto. A continuación se muestra el código que funciona con un clic de botón o un clic de anclaje.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="boton1">Click Aqui</button>
```

**Ajax**

```
$('#boton1').click(function() {
var a = $('#IdElemento1').val();
var b = $('#IdElemento2').val();

$.post('/prueba2.php', {'variableA': a, 'variableB': b}, function(data) {
    var valor= JSON.parse(data);
    if (valor== 'Completo') {
       setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = '/prueba2.php';
        }, 3000);//esto redirigirá al mismo archivo.php después de 3 segundos
    }
    else
    {
        alert ('Detalles Invalidos');
    }
});
});
```

y luego puede acceder a su archivo `prueba2.php` asi:

```
$a = $_POST['variableA'];
$b = $_POST['variableB'];
```